# What makes Google pick an alias (or non-alias) of a page to list in search?

Tags: seo, google-search, canonical-url

We have a ASP.NET web forms site and our product pages can be accessed from, for instance, `~/product.aspx?id=1234` or through an alias `~/store/a-great-product.aspx`.

The product is primarily searched by it's Catalog # (for example H1-GB234-L5)

On this one product, before October 2016, all of the traffic was coming in from the `~/product/aspx?id=1234` URL, but after that all traffic switched over to coming in from the `~/store/a-great-product.aspx` URL.

When I Google the Catalog #, the top result is the `~/store/a-great-product.aspx` as well.

What makes Google go with one alias, rather than the other one? Anything with Google that would have changed the traffic pattern?

Answer (score 1):

> What makes Google go with one alias, rather than the other one?

Usually the one that is linked to the most (internally and inbound). Presumably you aren't linking to both?!

URLs specified in the XML sitemap. (Although if the XML sitemap is different to your internal link structure then it will carry very little weight.)

You can also specify the canonical (preferred) URL in the `rel="canonical"` link element.

In this case, you should probably be 301 redirecting to the canonical URL.